# how do I get a PDF object (string,image,etc) that was touched by user?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-2d, ios

I am using CGPDF* set of classes to read a pdf document, is there a way to extract the object that was touched ('clicked') by user? In other way is there a way to get a PDF / (Quartz?) object at certain coordinates?

Comment: Users don't click anything on an iOS device, as they don't support mice. How are you showing the PDF content?

Comment: Using cgpdfdocument. I mean touch interaction like tapping a hyperlink

Comment: CGPDFDocument is a model class. How are you showing it to the user?

Comment: Oh you meant that :) Well sorry I am not very proficient with CocoaTouch/Quartz/Core Graphics yet. Well actually I am using UIScrollView with a subview in it with a CATiledLayer added as a layer

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
/* Code here */
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
}

Is there a way to get cooridnates for a given CGPDFObject? (or maybe my question is stupid/irrelevant?)
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive background about how to achieve this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914125).